# siebel and java integration using web services

Tags: web-services

I have a web application that exposes webservices, developed in java. 
One of the client system is a siebel platform; as they told me, they cannot manage arrays/list of objects.
Which is the best solution to solve the problem? 
How should I redesign my services? 
Consider that my data structure requirement includes list of objects...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The team who are telling you that Siebel cannot manage list of objects within a web service are not telling you the truth.  The Siebel application should be able to use your web service definitions to generate a proxy service within Siebel (which creates a Siebel internal web service definitions and integration objects).  These need to be compiled into the Siebel srf and mapped to internal Siebel integration objects which in turn need to be related to Siebel Business Objects and components.  It is certainly a non trivial piece of development if your team has not done it before but it is entirely possible.